# How to load data into CrowdFlower's job by using GATE's crowdsourcing plugin?

Tags: gate, crowdflower

I am trying to create a job on CrowdFlower using
GATE crowdsourcing plugin. My problem is I cannot load the data to the
job at all. What I have done so far in creating the job is:

1. Create job builder in PR.
2. Right click on the job builder and choose create a new CrowdFlower
   job. The job appeared in my job's list in CrowdFlower.
3. Populate corpus with some documents, pre-processing them with some
   ANNIE's application, e.g. tokenizer and sentence splitter
4. Add the job builder to a corpus pipeline, edit some parameters so
   they match with the initial annotations (tokens and sentences)
5. Run the pipeline. (Of course I make sure the Job ID match)

After I did all those, the job still has 0 row data. I am wondering if
I have done something wrong because I am sure that I follow all the instructions on [this tutorial](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun14/module-4-crowdsourcing/module4-crowdsourcing.pdf), specifically from page 28 to 35. Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have a typo in one of the job builder runtime parameters :)

Double-check the names of annotations and annotation sets, make sure all of them exist in your documents. If they exist and the builder found them, a cf_..._id feature should appear on each entity annotation.

If the job builder found any annotations it would call the crowdflower API and throw an exception if it fails to upload the data. It really sounds like it's not sending any requests and the only reason I see is it can't find annotations.